# adding space before and after a comma and dash in python using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I've already looked at so many topics on this and maybe I am not understanding something, but in a phrase like this:

"hello-goodbye       C-GOOD" or "100.89   D-FARM"
I want to add a space before and after characters like ".,-" but I don't want those spaces in C-GOOD or
D-FARM"

This is the final result I want:
"hello - goodbye      C-GOOD"  "100 . 89   D-FARM"
but no matter what I try I either get spaces on everything or no spaces on any of the dashes:

I either get: "hello - goodbye      C - GOOD" "100 . 89   D - FARM" or
"hello-goodbye      C-GOOD" "100 . 89   D-FARM"
Here is what I have tried:

```
text= re.sub(r'([.,!?()-]+)^(?<!C)', r' \1 ', text)
text= re.sub(r'([.,!?()-]+)^(?<!C-)', r' \1 ', text)
text= re.sub(r'([.,!?()-]+)(?<!C-GOOD)', r' \1 ', text)
text= re.sub(r'([.,!?()-]+)(?!C-GOOD)', r' \1 ', text)
```

If anyone can help or knows what I am doing wrong that would be wonderful. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mismatches `.,-` join uppercase letters.

```py
import re

s = "hello-goodbye C-GOOD 100.89 D-FARM"

print(re.sub("(?<![A-Z])([.,-])(?![A-Z]+)", r" \g<1> ", s))
# hello - goodbye C-GOOD 100 . 89 D-FARM
```

Comment: This solution would also spare things like `B-FARM`, whose `-` _should_ be replaced with spaces on both sides.

Comment: Thank-you so much, that worked perfectly. If possible do you know why my previous solutions did not work?

Comment: @SamSaidYes I think the definition of matching pattern needs to be ordered. For example: `^` needs to be at the beginning, `(?<!...)` needs to precede the string you want to match. You may need to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re) to see how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `re.sub` here with a callback function, which will exclude `C-GOOD` and `D-FARM` from being replaced:

```py
inp = ["hello-goodbye C-GOOD", "100.89 D-FARM"]
def repl(m):
    if m.group() == "C-GOOD" or m.group() == "D-FARM":
        return m.group()
    else:
        return " - "
output = [re.sub(r'C-GOOD|D-FARM|[.,-]', repl, x) for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['hello - goodbye C-GOOD', '100 - 89 D-FARM']
```

The trick here is in the regex pattern `C-GOOD|D-FARM|[.,-]`, which will attempt to match `C-GOOD` or `D-FARM` *before* attempting to also match a comma, dot, or dash.  `re.sub` then passes this match to a callback function, which only adds space in the case of the `[.,-]` separator.